# ResourceException: XA resource 'jdbc/wmsDatasource': resume for XID '..' raised -4: the supplied XID is invalid for this XA resource

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jdbc, atomikos

I am getting exception "the supplied XID is invalid for this XA resource" for one of my project to get records from DB ORACLE.

I found some solutions for "raised 3 and 5" but could not get for "raised -4".

Here I have attached log file for issue.

```
com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: XA resource 'jdbc/abcDatasource': resume for XID '31302E38382E3232382E3131352E746D32343536363030353837:31302E38382E3232382E3131352E746D31303437393130' raised -4: the supplied XID is invalid for this XA resource
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume(XAResourceTransaction.java:434) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.<init>(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:59) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:64) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:88) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na]
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandleState.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:179) ~[transactions-jta-3.9.3.jar:na] <br/>
```

[Configuration Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPZsB.png)

Let me know if any further information needed.

Comment: Please avoid putting the whole stack here, it's just too much, a couple of those lines would suffice. Also, put some of the code you're using, mainly how do you let Hibernate connect to the DB.

Comment: In the actual question please , not as comment.

Comment: Please **edit** your question with that information

Comment: updated with image

Comment: let's see the connection string.

Comment: Which version of atomikos are you using ? Also, could you add your transaction manager settings ?